# removing redundant columns when using get_dummies

Tags: python, pandas, categorical-data

Hi have a pandas dataframe `df` containing categorical variables.

```
df=pandas.DataFrame(data=[['male','blue'],['female','brown'],
['male','black']],columns=['gender','eyes'])

df
Out[16]: 
   gender   eyes
0    male   blue
1  female  brown
2    male  black
```

using the function get_dummies I get the following dataframe

```
df_dummies = pandas.get_dummies(df)

df_dummies
Out[18]: 
   gender_female  gender_male  eyes_black  eyes_blue  eyes_brown
0              0            1           0          1           0
1              1            0           0          0           1
2              0            1           1          0           0
```

Owever the columns `gender_female` and `gender_male` contain the same information because the original column could assume a binary value. Is there a (smart) way to keep only one of the 2 columns?

**UPDATED**

The use of

```
df_dummies = pandas.get_dummies(df,drop_first=True)
```

Would give me

```
df_dummies
Out[21]: 
   gender_male  eyes_blue  eyes_brown
0            1          1           0
1            0          0           1
2            1          0           0
```

but I would like to remove the columns for which originally I had only 2 possibilities

The desired result should be

```
df_dummies
Out[18]: 
   gender_male  eyes_black  eyes_blue  eyes_brown
0  1           0          1           0
1  0           0          0           1
2  1           1          0           0
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, you can use the argument `dropfirst`:

```
drop_first=True
```

From  the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html):

```
pd.get_dummies(pd.Series(list('abcaa')), drop_first=True)
   b  c
0  0  0
1  1  0
2  0  1
3  0  0
4  0  0
```

To have all dummy columns for `eyes`, and one for `gender`, use this:

```
df = pd.get_dummies(df, prefix=['eyes'], columns=['eyes'])
df = pd.get_dummies(df,drop_first=True)
```

Output:

```
       eyes_black  eyes_blue  eyes_brown  gender_male
0           0          1           0            1
1           0          0           1            0
2           1          0           0            1
```

More general:

```
   gender   eyes    heigh
0    male   blue     tall
1  female  brown    short
2    male  black  average

for i in df.columns:
    if len(df.groupby([i]).size()) > 2:
         df = pd.get_dummies(df, prefix=[i], columns=[i])
df = pd.get_dummies(df, drop_first=True)
```

Output:

```
   eyes_black  eyes_blue  eyes_brown  heigh_average  heigh_short  heigh_tall  \
0           0          1           0              0            0           1   
1           0          0           1              0            1           0   
2           1          0           0              1            0           0    

   gender_male  
0            1  
1            0  
2            1
```

Comment: but this would delete also eyes_black that I would like to keep. I would like to remove only if it is binary

Comment: Actually removing `eyes_black` would still give you the information that the eyes are black. Like the example of the documentation, if a row is all 0, then it is `a`

Comment: that's true, but in my case it is important to know what is the 3rd option... for gender I know that if it is not male will be female, but for other variables not..

Comment: thanks. but I have many features... that was just an example.. I wanted to come up with a general rule/function... I don't think that any parameter of get_dummies can do what I want

Comment: one general rule for binary and not binary data?

Comment: yes looking for this rule...and integrate it in get_dummies

Answer (score 1):

You could use `itertools.combinations` to find all pairs of columns, then any potentially redundant pair of columns will be one where for every row one column is True and the other is False - i.e. an XOR:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['male','blue'],['female','brown'],['male','black']],
                  columns=['gender','eyes'])

dummies = pd.get_dummies(df)

for c1, c2 in combinations(dummies.columns, 2):
    if all(dummies[c1] ^ dummies[c2]):
        print(c1,c2)
```

However, this also notices that in your examples all females have brown eyes, hence we get the following printed:

```
gender_female gender_male
gender_male eyes_brown
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can split the dataframe into parts you want to apply `drop_first=True` and parts you don't. Then concatenate them together.

```
df1 = df.iloc[:, 0:2]
df2 = df.iloc[:, 2:]
df1 = pd.get_dummies(df1 ,drop_first=True)

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```